# Define individual events with sub handles

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub routine that handles multiple labels being clicked on.

```
Private Sub Label_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label9.Click, Label8.Click, Label7.Click, Label6.Click, Label5.Click, Label4.Click, Label3.Click, Label2.Click, Label16.Click, Label15.Click, Label14.Click, Label13.Click, Label12.Click, Label11.Click, Label10.Click
        checkCards()
    End Sub
```

While this works, the problem is that I want each individual label to have a slightly different action each time, such as

```
checkCards(labelClicked)
```

I want each label to be able to be clicked on and call the same `checkCards()` sub, however with slightly different values of the parentheses. How would I go about this?

I am somewhat new to Visual Basic, so please try to keep the answer basic.

Comment: checkCards(DirectCast(sender, Label))

Answer (score 3):

The `sender` parameter of your event is the clicked `Label`:

```
Private Sub Label_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label9.Click, Label8.Click, Label7.Click, Label6.Click, Label5.Click, Label4.Click, Label3.Click, Label2.Click, Label16.Click, Label15.Click, Label14.Click, Label13.Click, Label12.Click, Label11.Click, Label10.Click
    checkCards(sender)
End Sub
```

So if you click on the `Label1` the `sender` parameter contains the `Label1` object.

So you can implement the sub `checkCards` like the following:

```
Private Sub checkCards(ByVal labelClicked As Label)
    Select Case labelClicked.Name
        Case Label1.Name
            'do some stuff if Label1 was clicked.
        Case Label2.Name
            'do some stuff if Label2 was clicked.
        Case Label3.Name, Label4.Name
            'do some stuff if Label3 or Label4 was clicked.
        Case Else
            'do some stuff if none of the above labels was clicked.
    End Select
End Sub
```